# is $ f(x)⋅e^{ix} = f(x)^* ⋅ e^{-ix} $ true? If so why?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

While trying to understand proof for **Parseval’s theorem** I came across a method which seems to say that:

$$   f(x)⋅e^{ix} = f(x)^* ⋅ e^{-ix} $$

**why** can I **change the sign** of the e-function after **complex conjugating** my f(x) ?

(this is the site i derived this from, equ.4 the $g(w')^*e^{-iw't}$ : [http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jdg/eeft3.pdf](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ejdg/eeft3.pdf))

Comment: What about if $f(x)=1$ for instance? Surely we don't have $e^{ix} = e^{-ix}$ in general.

Comment: Perhaps the expression on the left is meant to be wrapped in parens and conjugated, i.e.,$$\left( f(x) \cdot e^{ix} \right)^{*} = ...$$

Comment: no, it wasn't meant to be wrapped. I think it must not be true :(

Comment: As written, it's certainly false.

Comment: The justification for equation (4) in your source document seems to be the following. They use (3) to express $f(t)$, this is clear; then they use (3) again but taking the complex conjugate to express $g(t)^*$. If it's unclear why in general $(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t) dt)^*=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t)^* dt$, you could create a new question. (The conjugate of a product, inside the integral, is as per MATHBOI's answer, following John Hughes' correction to the statement of your existing question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the complex conjugate,
$$f(x)^*(e^{ix})^*=f(x)^*(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^*=f(x)^*(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))=f(x)^*e^{-ix}$$
Here I have used Euler's Identity. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou! But wouldnt this only be true for:
$ [f(x)⋅exp(ix)]^* = f(x)^*exp(ix)^* = f(x)^*exp(-ix)$  ?

Comment: If I understand the question. I think the above does indeed require $f(x)=f(x)^*$

Comment: So only for functions that are not complex then ?

Comment: That's correct! And I'm pretty sure this is true in the context of the theorem :). Namely $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Oh! that's fantastic! Thank you so much :D

Comment: Hang on .. If $f(x)=f(x)^*$ then from my first equation $e^{ix}$ would equal $e^{-ix}$ ^^'

Comment: Generally $(ab)^*=a^*b^*$.